# Why use "that of" here?

Tags: pronouns, demonstrative-pronouns

Here is the sentence in my grammar book:

> "The circulation of weekly magazines exceeded **that of** newspapers in
> that period."

I can't understand the usage of "that of"; can anyone help me explain it?

Comment: This is the anaphoric use of "that", a pro-form that has the NP "the circulation" as antecedent. We understand _The circulation of weekly magazines exceeded the circulation of newspapers in that period._

Comment: In simpler words, "that" is a pronoun that stands for "the circulation"

Comment: It's not a pronoun. The demonstratives like "that" are determinatives.